# Doxygen LaTeX output paragraph indentation

Tags: latex, doxygen

I have an SW manual that I'm documenting with Doxygen+Markdown, the output being a PDF file. The default Doxygen LaTeX header uses `\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}`. I tried to change that to `\setlength{\parindent}{20pt}`, but the output PDF still doesn't have indented paragraphs. I was wondering if I need to change the `doxyparagraph` style.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I'm using text and other content from Markdown files. Looking at a TeX file from one of these MD files, I can't see anything special(environment, etc) aboout how thery're being defined. In a MD file I have:

```
### Boot Initialization {#prom_rom_boot_initialization}
The boot ROM performs basic system initialization required for booting the
system. The system initialization consists of the following:
```

This generates:

```
\hypertarget{program_rom_chapter_prom_rom_boot_initialization}{}\doxysubsubsection{Boot Initialization}\label{program_rom_chapter_prom_rom_cfx_boot_initialization}
The boot R\+OM performs basic system initialization required for booting the system. The system initialization consists of the following\+:
```

The `doxysubsection` is defined in the default Doxygen LaTeX style as:

```
\newcommand\doxysubsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\raggedright\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
```

So I tried to do the following in my header:

```
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
    \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{0ex}{-1.0ex}{1.0ex}{%
        \setlength{\parindent}{20pt}%
        \normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\SS@parafont%
    }%
}
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}{%
    \@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{0ex}{-1.0ex}{1.0ex}{%
        \setlength{\parindent}{20pt}%
        \normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\SS@subparafont%
    }%
}
\makeatother
```

That didn't work.

So I tried setting `parindent` in my document:

```
\documentclass[parindent=20pt,10pt,twoside,openany]{book}
```

And use the ragged2e package. I've added

```
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{\parindent}
```

To my header. And set `\parindent=20pt` instead of `\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}`.

I still don't get indented paragraphs.

Comment: By default doxygen sets the `\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}` if you want to set it just for the paragraphs you could change the `doxyparagraph` style by renewing the command in an extra stylesheet handed to doxygen by means of `LATEX_EXTRA_STYLESHEET`, but be careful and also take into account the settings for the other sections and subparagraph commands and the `DoxyParagraph` environment setting.

Comment: @albert Thank you for your answer but doesn't `DoxyParagraph` only work for `@par`? What about text from Markdown files? I've also edited my question with some things I tried. Thanks!

Comment: regarding `DoxyParagraph` in the `doxygen.sty` I save: `% Used by @par and @paragraph`  but this is probably a false positive. Looks also like in your description of `doxysubsection` the last line is missing and I don't understand the `So I tried to do the following in my header:` as the command `\renewcommand{\paragraph}` for doxygen is `\renewcommand{\doxyparagraph}` and why use `\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\SS@parafont` and not the doxygen used `{\raggedright\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}`?

Comment: @albert, I get that from `doxygen -w latex header_orig.tex footer_orig.tex doxygen_orig.sty`

Comment: Strange, which doxygen version? (doxygen -v)

Comment: `doxygen.exe -v : 1.8.17 (b5fa3cd1c6e6240e20d3b80a70e3f04040b32021*)`

Comment: In line 563 of the sty file I see: `\newcommand\doxyparagraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\raggedright\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}` note also the `\newcommand\doxyparagraph` so with `doxy` before `paragraph`

Comment: @albert, if you look at my edited question, I don't see a `doxyparagraph` in the generated TeX files from Markdown, whence I was trying to redefine `paragraph`. Another thing: doesn't `raggedright` sets `parindent` to zero?

Comment: I think there has been a bit of confusion. When I understand it correct you want to "indent" the body text of a paragraph (actually a subsubsection). The doxy... commands have nothing to do with them, they just steer the "caption" / "title" of the paragraph. In the refman.tex I see also the `renewcommand`s, my first thought was the you were at the wrong level here and needed `\renewcommand{\subsubsection}` (I also tried section and subsection) but I couldn't get this to work either.